# Catching exceptions thrown from UserControl in parent Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a Form that extends some class that has special exception-handling logic to present any that arise to the user in a clean manner.  That Form contains a custom UserControl that has the potential to throw Exceptions which, if unaddressed, aren't caught and rethrown by the parent Form, and therefore don't hit the special logic.

How can I hook things up so that my UserControl throws exceptions *to* my Form?

Comment: You can't do that. That's not how exceptions work. They always go up the call stack. They have no concept of what a user control is. If your design requires that you catch user control exceptions in the parent, then stop right now and do a redesign. There's no way to do what you want, and you shouldn't want to do it in any case.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Obviously, you're right at the most specific levels - that exceptions naturally go up the call-stack - but the idea is that they ought to flow from child to parent.  In this case, the parent who needs to respond to errors at the child's level isn't the direct owner of the child's context.  It's fairly commonly seen.

Comment: "They ought to"? In which universe? Not in _this_ one! Beware of inventing architectures for software someone else has already written.

Comment: Perhaps I misstated my goal, then.  I'm trying to send information from the UserControl to the parent Form.  Could you perhaps provide some guidance as to how I can achieve this?  Criticism comes cheap.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution would be to put a try .. catch into your usercontrol and to raise an event that could be handled by the parent form.

You would pass the exception as an event argument.

*Note that I think that this is probably not the right way of dealing with exceptions, I'm just answering your question.*

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be the exception itself; just a message conveying the information that an exception occurred.  Could you elaborate on how this might look/is done?  I'm new to WinForms.

Comment: FYI, you just answered his question by giving the wrong answer and by providing a bad example. Imagine if the OP and many of the future thousands of readers of this answer actually go and _implement_ this suggestion! It will be your fault.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I believe that the OP should go ahead and implement his code this way. This is especially true if the code is important. That way, when the entire house of cards falls down, the OP will have learned _not to fight the platform_. The fact that WinForms has no facility to implement this means that _you should not implement this_!

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I just told him what he was looking for, even if he was asking to shoot on his foot and I warned him that it was going to hurt. I'm not here to judge anyone, just to give help to anyone requesting it.

Comment: So, that makes you a criminal as well - accessory to foot-shooting.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: euthanasia is not a crime imho, so assisting someone to shoot himself is ok as well as long as that is what he wishes :) Is me or is this becoming crazy?

Comment: It's certainly gone as far as it can go without _becoming_ crazy.